# Why are there so many Javascript variables defined but not used in webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, http

Please forgive my ignorance, I just started learning about `JavaScript` and `HTML`. When I inspect the source code of many webpages I found there are many `<script>` tags with only a variable defined in between, such as the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var moove_frontend_activity_scripts = {"activityoptions":"","referer":"","ajaxurl":"https:\/\/ayso.org\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","post_id":"4","is_page":"1","is_single":"","current_user":"0","referrer":""};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

And the defined variable is never used within the webpage. I wonder why such variables are declared and what is the use of them?

Comment: Are you sure they're not used by external scripts which are included by the page?

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure and I did not know. I just focused on the single page content and forgot external scripts will be brought in when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When those variables are defined in a script using `var`, outside a closure, they are automatically added to the `window` object. While they might not occur anywhere else in the page when viewing the markup, it's quite probable that they're being accessed from another external script loaded into the page.

Answer (score 3):

In isolation you are right. There's no point in defining a variable if it isn't used.

However, other scripts (embedded via `<script>`) might still use this.